# Old Jquery filter not working in latest version1.7.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabnavigator

I have working copy of tab navigation in my application, i tried to update the jquery to latest(1.7.2) , for this i have downloaded jquery-1.7.2.min.js from jquery website . After updating this the following line not working as expected `tabContainers.hide().filter(':member').show();`

here is the full jquery method.

```
                $(function () {
                var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
                tabContainers.hide().filter(':member').show();

                $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
                    var hash = window.location.hash || '#member';        
                    tabContainers.hide();
                    tabContainers.filter(hash).show();
                    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
                    $('a[hash=' + hash + ']').addClass('selected');
                   document.getElementById("submitform").action="newaction.action"+hash;
                });

                $(window).trigger( "hashchange" );
            });
```

here is the html part

```
                <ul class="tabNavigation">
                    <li><a href="#member">Tab1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
               </ul>
               <div id="member">content goes here</div>
               <div id="tab2 . . .
```

**Update:** changing :member to #member or :first loading the content of first div, but still the first li is not got selected.(members tab)

Comment: In the list of `basic filters` here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-filter-selectors/, I dont find a `:member` filter.

Comment: And how did it work before the update?

Comment: @Joy Here member is id of the first tab(li element) FYI: it is working with v1.3.1.

Comment: @gnanz then it should be `#member`. and It should not work with v1.3.1 either, can you share any url so we can check?

Comment: change `tabContainers.hide().filter(':member').show();` to `tabContainers.hide().filter('#member').show();` and it will work. You can also use `tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();`

Comment: yeah both #member and :first displaying first div content- so this part is ok, but still the member li is not getting selected,is there any update needed in  `$('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
                    $('a[hash=' + hash + ']').addClass('selected');` these lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: With a working hashchange handler, the line `tabContainers.hide().filter(':member').show();` will be nullified when `$(window).trigger("hashchange");` fires. Any attempt to fix `tabContainers.hide().filter(':member').show();` is therefore futile and the statement can be deleted.

Second: There's a cross-browser issue with `location.hash`, namely that some browsers return a string with a leading '#' and some don't. This requires the returned string to be normalized.

Taking these factors into account, you might like to try:

```
$(function() {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div'),
        submitform = $("#submitform");

    $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
        var hash = (location.hash=='' || location.hash=='#') ? '#member' : location.hash;
        var hashNormalized = (hash.match(/^#/)) ? hash : '#'+hash;
        tabContainers.hide().filter(hashNormalized).show();
        $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected').filter(function() {
            return this.hash == hashNormalized;
        }).addClass('selected');
        submitform.attr('action', 'newaction.action' + hashNormalized);
    }).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Tested in Opera 11.64 and IE9. *Be sure to test in FF*

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kuw8X/2/)

The `.filter(function(){...})` approach to filtering the anchors should immunise you against differences between jQuery versions.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eNmX/)
.With 1.3.2 and older version only `filter('#id')` works but not `filter(':id')`.I am not sure how it worked for you.

Update `tabContainers.hide().filter(':member').show();` to `tabContainers.hide().filter('#member').show()`;

Comment: yeah both #member and :first displaying first div content- so this part is ok, but still the member li is not getting selected,is there any update needed in  `$('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
                    $('a[hash=' + hash + ']').addClass('selected');` these lines

Comment: Try `$('a[href=' + hash + ']').addClass('selected');`

Comment: @ AhamedMustafaM yeah href= is working, btw do you have any idea why hash= is not working

Comment: Because there is no property called `hash` for the `<a>` element

Comment: Previously both :memeber and hash= works. Here is 
[Jquery1.3.1](http://jsfiddle.net/ursgnanz/eZWtb/) file-what i was using in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either this

```
 tabContainers.hide().filter('#member').show();
```

or

```
tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();
```

To show the first div with id `member`.

And to highlight the corresponding `a`

Change this

```
$('a[hash=' + hash + ']').addClass('selected');
```

To

```
$('a[href=' + hash + ']').addClass('selected');
```

As `hash` is not the attribute name, it's `href`.